# how to remove (purge) miktex?

Tags: apt, package-management, 20.04, updates, dpkg

Recently I upgraded my ubuntu 18.04.05 LTS to 20.04.1 LTS and installed miktex, to manager packages on tex studio. Anyway, I cannot open miktex consele or even exclude it through terminal, when I try, I got this message:

```
Após esta operação, será libertado 102 MB de espaço em disco.
W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/somerville-dla-team-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/somerville-dla-team-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list:3
Deseja continuar? [S/n] s
(A ler a base de dados ... 274501 ficheiros e directórios actualmente instalados.)
A remover miktex (20.12-bionic1) ...
miktexsetup: /usr/bin/../lib/libstdc++.so.6: version "GLIBCXX_3.4.22" not found (required by /usr/bin/../lib/libmiktex-core.so.22)
miktexsetup: /usr/bin/../lib/libstdc++.so.6: version "GLIBCXX_3.4.22" not found (required by /usr/bin/../lib/libmiktex-packagemanager.so.10)
dpkg: erro ao processar o pacote miktex (--remove):
 o subprocesso instalado, do pacote miktex, o script pre-removal retornou erro do status de saída 1
dpkg: demasiados erros, a parar
Foram encontrados erros enquanto processava:
 miktex
O processamento parou porque ocorreram demasiados erros.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

with  strings /usr/bin/../lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX_" , i got this message: GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_3.4.20
GLIBCXX_3.4.21
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

How to proceed properly to exclude it?

Comment: Can you provide the output of `strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX_`?

Comment: And also for `strings /usr/bin/../lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX_`? Thanks

Comment: hello @dariofac, thanks for the answer. How can provide the output of  "strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX_" and "strings /usr/bin/../lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX_" ? Sorry, i'm kind new on linux (ubuntu)

Comment: @dariofac, i put "strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX_"  on terminal and got "permission denied"

Comment: Try instead with `sudo strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX_`, thanks